# Android custom keyboard: change candidate height

Tags: android, user-interface, keyboard

I'm writing a custom keyboard and I want to use the candidate.
But the candidate view is set to a certin height which is to small for my needs.
I cant seem to set the height of the candidate. if I set the height to certine dp i get half black screen.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **height** of the Android Custom Keyboard candidate view could be chang from `CandidateView.java` file. Open the file and find the below line:

```
final int desiredHeight = ((int) mPaint.getTextSize()) + mVerticalPadding
                + padding.top + padding.bottom;
```

And add number with it as follow:

```
final int desiredHeight = ((int) mPaint.getTextSize()) + mVerticalPadding
                + padding.top + padding.bottom + 20;
```

The `20` at the end of code line increases the height of candidate view.